# How to put code on thread in ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, c#-4.0

I have the following ActionResult method:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(string someXml)
{
  //parse someXml
  return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Ok);
}
```

I need to return the HTTP status code immediately.  If I put the return before the Xml parsing, the parsing will not occur.  Can I throw the parsing onto another thread so the return is sent immediately?

It would sequentially look like:

```
//put xml parsing into method, create new thread and call parsing method
//do return
```

Are there any side affects to running another thread in an ASP.NET MVC app?  Or is there a better option?

Comment: Do you need to return anything else to the client once the parsing is complete?

Comment: Nope.  Just the Http return code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is like a "fire and forget" type scenario, all that's really needed is to launch another thread:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(string someXml)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {
        //parse someXml
    } );

    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Ok);
}
```

ASP.Net MVC provides an [`AsyncController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but that does not apply here.  It's useful when you want to hold the request for a long-running operation, and return something to the client once completed, without blocking the app pool thread.